# Не могу применить стили другому классу при помощи :hover

Tags: html, css

Допустим я хочу поменять цвет блока при наведении на ссылку, но почему то ничего не работает. Видел видео где в стилях не было + между .link:hover и .block и все нормально работало

```
<body>
        <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
        <div class="block"></div>
</body>
```

CSS styles

```
.block {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.link:hover .block {
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: Ваш `div` должен быть внутри `a` чтобы это правило сработало

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.block {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.link:hover + .block {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> поменять цвет блока при наведении на ссылку

Как вариант...

```css
.block {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.link:hover + .block {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="#" class="link">Link</a>
  <div class="block"></div>
</body>
```